# Counting number of floating point operations in javascript

Tags: javascript, profiling, time-complexity

I am attempting to write a scientific article about an algorithm I developed and coded in javascript. I was hoping to compare the old, slow version against the new, fast version for various inputs and be able to report back some metrics like the number of calls to Math.log, number of calls to Math.exp, number of multiplication operations, number of division operations, number of additions, number of subtractions, etc.

I realize that the JIT compiler of the javascript engine could do some optimization that changes these numbers a bit, but I don't really care about the exact details of each metric, but only that I am comparing apples to apples across both algorithms.

Is there any tool or method for automatically counting these operations in javascript? Are there any javascript engines that generate some type of intermediate bytecode that would allow these operations to be automatically counted? If not javascript, what about in c++?

Comment: Chrome might show the number of calls to `Math.x` in their profile results.

Comment: Javascript allows you to redefine built-in methods,. for example -> `var oLog = Math.log; Math.log = (x) => { console.log('log'); return oLog(x); }`  would console out `log` and return the original log.  So if you have not got too many functions you want to profile, this simple method might do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example of wrapping the original Math.sin & Math.log, and keep a count of the calls.

This works because in Javascript you even have the power to replace built-in's..

```js
let counts = {};

function profileProc(root, name, proc) {
  let oProc = proc;
  root[name] = function() {
    counts[name] = counts[name] ? counts[name] + 1 : 1;
    return oProc.apply(proc, arguments);
  }
}

profileProc(Math, 'log', Math.log);
profileProc(Math, 'sin', Math.sin);

console.log(Math.log(10));
console.log(Math.sin(10));
console.log(Math.sin(20));

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely use that for the Math.x functions. I'm more worried about the basic * / + - operation though. Any ideas for these?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like I found something that works. As part of paper.js, there is a scripting language called [PaperScript](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscript/) which parses code written in a javascript syntax and adds operator overloading as explained [here](http://strd6.com/2011/06/operator-overloading-in-paperscript/). Basically paper.js provides the `paper.PaperScript.compile(code)` function takes javascript code and replaces each mathematical operation with a call to

```
function __$__(left, operator, right) {...}
```

So an expression like var `var c = a * b;` becomes `var c = __$__(a, '*', b);` Once this transformation is made, it is simple to modify the `__$__` function in order to count operations:

```
window.operatorCounts = {};
window.operatorCounts['+'] = 0;
window.operatorCounts['-'] = 0;
window.operatorCounts['*'] = 0;
window.operatorCounts['/'] = 0;
window.operatorCounts['%'] = 0;
window.operatorCounts['=='] = 0;
window.operatorCounts['!='] = 0;

function __$__(left, operator, right) {
  window.operatorCounts[operator]++;
  switch (operator) {
  case '+': return left + right;
  case '-': return left - right;
  case '*': return left * right;
  case '/': return left / right;
  case '%': return left % right;
  case '==': return left == right;
  case '!=': return left != right;
  default:
    throw new Error('Implement Operator: ' + operator);
  }
};
```

After this instrumented version of operators is defined, it's a simple matter to run the new compiled function. By combining this with Keith's answer for the Math.x functions, I was able to accomplish what I set out to do.